# Is react component props types need for production?

Tags: reactjs

I think, Prop type validation happens only in development mode. Can I remove it from production build? So that reduces bundle and memory usage

Comment: you can check this, may be it helped you - https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/209

Comment: Definitely. Use [babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types)